# PyCharm - installing libraries with wheelhouse

Tags: python, libraries, python-wheel

Due to network constraints I had to install libraries with a wheelhouse file. In this wheelhouse I had the `requirements.txt` file and a `whl` file that contained all the `.whl` files.

I then ran the command `pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index --find-links whl --user` to install all the requirements and dependencies. When I hit the `pip freeze` command, it shows that all the dependencies have been installed, **INCLUDING** python package `python-dateutil==2.8.1`.

Yet when I try to import `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` , the module name is recognized but it raises the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateutil'`.

I tried to `pip install .\python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl`. It says that requirements are **already satisfied**. I'm a bit lost on why this error occurs.

Comment: Two Pythons? Virtual environments?

Comment: When I go to settings in pyCharm and look for Python Interpreter, the path is ```Python 3.7 D:\Users\bouh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe```. It seems to me that it is not a virtual environement. And to my knowledge I only have one python